# Subtracting if column is checked and takes correspoding number

Tags: excel, vba, lookup

Thanks for viewing this post

I hope I explain this question properly.

I have 2 columns A and B. Column A has some numbers that are calculated with a formula. Column B has only "a" in certain rows in Webdings font. "A" in webdings is a checkmark and is a visual indicator of completed task that I input.

What I want to do is take a fixed number say, 10 and subtract the values from column A based on completed tasks by looking at column B.

I can't post a screenshot yet as I am a new user.

UPDATE: It is in Excel 2010 VBA language

Comment: We're going to need more details than that. What language/db is this? What's your existing code?

Comment: It is in Excel 2010 VBA language.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should try something out before posting such open ended questions. but here is a code that should do the work for you.

```
Sub Test

Dim FixNum as Long
FixNum = 10 'This is the number you want to subtract.

For i = 2 to Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If Range("B" & i).Value = "A" then Range("A" & i).Value = (Range("A" & i).Value - FixNum)
next i

end Sub
```